# Regex matching multiple prefixes, unpack to columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Any suggestions for a regex to take this series

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    'Apple: very tasty',
    'Banana: Unpleasant',
    'Apple: quite nice  Banana: not bad either',
    '',
]

ser = pd.Series(data=data)
```

[image]

into this resulting DataFrame?

```python
pd.DataFrame(data=[
    ['very tasty', np.nan],
    [np.nan, 'Unpleasant'],
    ['quite nice', 'not bad either'],
    [np.nan, np.nan],
], columns = ['Apple', 'Banana'])
```

[image]

If Apple and Banana exist, they are always in the order Apple, Banana, and separated by a **double** space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,2),
                      index=np.repeat(np.arange(df.shape[0]),df.shape[1]//2))
```

<strike>df_out = pd.DataFrame()</strike>

<strike>df = ser.str.split(':|\s\s',expand=True)</strike>

<strike>for n,g in df.groupby(df.columns // 2, axis=1):</strike>

<strike>df_out = pd.concat([df_out, pd.DataFrame(g.values)])</strike>

```
df_out.set_index(0, append=True)[1].unstack().dropna(1, how='all')
```

Output:

```
         Apple           Banana
0   very tasty              NaN
1          NaN       Unpleasant
2   quite nice   not bad either
3          NaN              NaN
```